# Elastic Search 1000 bool conditions in a single query not giving results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to query keywords with certain combinations using bool (must) condition(total conditions count go beyond 1000) in ES query, but Elastic search is either giving response timeout or going down.

Comment: @Shahank can you share the ES logs during your request?

Comment: You have to change configuration first, read :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html